# Magickwand C change image color

Tags: c, image-processing, imagemagick, magickwand

I have a method called single_color for image. It changes the color of an image. It was working on my previous image magick version but after upgraded my version, it's not working.

**ImageMagick Version**

Version: ImageMagick 7.0.5-9 Q16 x86_64 2017-06-01

To achieve this I do this.

- Change all color to output color except transparent.

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <MagickWand/MagickWand.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  MagickWand * wand;
  wand  = NewMagickWand();
  MagickReadImage(wand, "input.png");

  PixelWand * PW3, * PW4;

  PW3 = NewPixelWand();
  PW4 = NewPixelWand();

  PixelSetColor(PW3,"transparent");
  PixelSetColor(PW4,"#008080");
  MagickOpaquePaintImage(wand, PW3, PW4, 20.0*65535.0/100.0, MagickTrue);

  MagickWriteImage(wand, "single_color.png");
}
```

Comment: 1) There is no code in your "code". It is all declarations and syntax errors.  2) C does not support _methods_. 3) Learn [ask].

Comment: I just posted the methods needed in that. Let me update it

Comment: Now I think the code works. May I know the reason behind down-vote @Olaf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in ImageMagick's latest version. I posted this on their forum. It might be fixed soon.

[Check this.](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=32081&p=146606#p146606)